# How to join chatoom room automatically using smack

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

Using smack I am creating connection(**usera**), and after that I am joining to the chatrooms by getting the list of chatrooms. But after this if another user(**userb**) adds the **usera** into a new chatroom. But how can I automatically join to the newly created chatroom?

Below is the code to get list of chatrooms and joining chatroom. But in the list I am getting all public chatrooms. How can I get the list of chatrooms in which **usera** is participant/memeber?

```
List<DomainBareJid> mucServiceDomains = connection.mucManager.getMucServiceDomains();

       //get list of chatrooms
                for (DomainBareJid domainBareJid : mucServiceDomains) {
                    List<HostedRoom> hostedRooms = connection.mucManager.getHostedRooms(domainBareJid);
                    for (HostedRoom hostedRoom : hostedRooms) {
                        Log.info("hostedRooms::: jid{}  name{}",hostedRoom.getJid(),hostedRoom.getName());
                        try {
                            connection.joinRoom(hostedRoom.getJid().toString(), connection.getUserJid().toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.error("Error joinign muc::{}",e);
                        }
                    }
                }


       // joinroom by room name
    public boolean joinRoom(String mGroupChatName, String mNickName) {
        Log.debug("joinRoom " + mGroupChatName + " " + mNickName);
        if(mGroupChatName!=null) {
            try {
                MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat = groupchats.get(mGroupChatName);

                if (mMultiUserChat == null)
                {
                    mMultiUserChat = mucManager.getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(mGroupChatName));
                    mMultiUserChat.addInvitationRejectionListener(this);
                    groupchats.put(mGroupChatName, mMultiUserChat);
                }
                DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
                history.setMaxStanzas(0);
                mMultiUserChat.join(Resourcepart.from(mNickName),null,history,SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
                mMultiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Message message) {
                        Log.info("MUC message recieved is::{}",message.getBody());

                    }
                });
                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.error("joinRoom", e);

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Smack version: 4.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

When some user wants another user to join a chat room, then that user can send an invitation to the other user to join that chat room. The process is specified in [section 7.8 of XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#invite).